# Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time (xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am a new learner to Swift and I am trying to make BMR calculator. When I implemented to BMR equation I got this error "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions". I tried to break the equation down put it did not work.

Here is my equation

```
let BMR = (((10 * weightField) + (6.25 * heightField) - (5 * ageField) + 5))
```

Comment: `weightField `   , `heightField`  and  `ageField`   what is this parameter how you declare it

Comment: One of the most difficult things for the compiler to do is type inference. If you tell the compiler what BMR is then it will prob make this go away. `let BMR: int = ...` for instance.

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish UITextField

Comment: The first two and last two parentheses are unnecessary. In fact, all of the parentheses are unnecessary due to the order of operations.

Comment: @Fogmeister I changed it to `let BMR: int =` and it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is compiler issue because `weightField` , `heightField` `ageField` is Text fields

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var weightField:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightField:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageField:UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        let weight  = Double(weightField.text ?? "0") ?? 0 
        let height  = Double(heightField.text ?? "0")  ?? 0
        let age  = Double(ageField.text ?? "0") ?? 0 

        let BMR = ((10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) + 5)
        print(BMR)

    }

}
```

Comment: Conversion to double returns an optional.

Comment: Did not fix it.

Comment: Code updated I just force it I just told you the idea

Comment: @Adam If you want anybody to actually help you, you'll have to give them a bit more feedback than a downvote and "Did not fix it"

Comment: @Alexander I did not give him a downvote. What feedback do you want? He gave me a line of code I tried it and it did not work. I got the same error.

Comment: @adam "I got the same error" and how were we supposed to know that?

Comment: @Alexander If it was not the same I would write it did fix it, however, I got another error. Then I would mention the other error!

Comment: This code won't work since you can't add optional `Double`.

Comment: @rmaddy  where is optional double

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish Double string initializer is fallible. It returns an optional Double

Comment: If it fail it will be 0  string using ??

Comment: you are using it at the text property instead of the double initializer. check the correct syntax at my comment at the answer above

Comment: Yes see it above string will be 0 if it is nil

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish No, you are missing the issue. If the user types "Hello" then `Double("Hello")` returns `nil`. `weight`, `height`, and `age` are of type `Double?`, not `Double`. So your code using those variables to calculate `BMR` won't compile.

Comment: @rmaddy  yes I got it